# Test static library or share it between projects

Tags: iphone, xcode, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am going to make a static library which will be used in several of my applications. This library will also be released so that everybody can use it. Therefore I am not interested in anyone seeing the code and that it is very easy to implement in a project.

I have chosen to use [Michael Tyson's template for universal static libraries](https://github.com/michaeltyson/iOS-Universal-Library-Template). This template relies on the Adam Martins universal static library script.

Now, I would like a way to test my library on a device and as I need to use this library in other projects, I was thinking just to link it to another project and test the library through this project. I just can't figure out how I would accomplish this. Can anyone guide me through this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy all your .h files from the library project to your new project and then just drag and drop the library to your new project... don't copy the library into your new project .. this way if you make any changes in the library they will be reflected in your projet and you won't have to repeat the process again.. (just make sure both the builds are same for example if you develop the library using device scheme than your project should also compile under the device scheme. you can make a FAT library as well but that will require more work and you can look into it later.) hoping this helps..

you can refer [this](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/) tutorial for some more graphic info..

Comment: This works, but will require that I drag every header file in when it's created. Also, this way the library is not compiled through my "new project" (the app itself) and thus will have to be compiled from the library project. Isn't there a way to link the two together, so that the static library will be a dependency and will be compiled when my app project is compiled? Also, isn't there a way to avoid having to drag every header file into the project?

Comment: I usually do this and never tried what you are suggesting as my projects are small and as far dragging each .h file is required , there is a way around by forward declaring those class which are used internally by the library and not the project. this way u only need to add .h files for classes which use your project uses directly... and anyway usually XCODE discovers the dependencies automatically so if you make changes in the library than it should compile the library itself if you compile the app.

Comment: Thinking about it, it might not be so bad again. After all, this is the way the end user is supposed to use the library. To minimize the header hassle, I have created one header file which imports the other header files and added this to my projects prefix. Thereby, it's really nothing but dragging new header files into the project. Thank you for your help.